# What is the difference between if(b) and if(b==true) in java language?

Tags: java, boolean

If b is a Boolean, what is the difference between `if(b)` and `if(b==true)`?

Comment: They evaluate to the same thing - effectively no difference

Comment: Former is correct (& short) way, later is 'a' way to do - developers in their learning phase use it - until they know the better thing.

Answer (score 8):

There isn't any difference, unless one day you mistakenly replace the 2nd expression to this:

```
if (b = true)
```

and then you spend hours debugging what's the issue, you'll feel the need of using the first one.

Comment: Is there a any speed issue between them?

Comment: @BAEHARAM Well, there isn't. But here's a suggestion - don't think too much about efficiency while programming, specially in the beginning stage. First get the result. These are just pre-mature optimization, which shouldn't exist.

Comment: Thanks your comment :) but I have to know about the difference because of colleague homework. So is it related to only debugging problems?

Comment: @BAEHARAM Ok, just to finish this discussion, they are both the same. It's upto you what you choose to use. I've already given hint in my answer, about which one you should use.

Answer (score 2):

`if (b)` evaluates the value of `b`, which means the conditions is met if `b` is true.

`if (b==true)` evaluates the value of the expressions `b==true`, and this expression evaluates to true if and only if `b` is true.

Therefore both expressions have the same outcome.

Comment: I know they have the same outcome, but are they compiled the same way? Could'nt it be possible that `if ( b==true )` gets compiled in more lines of machine code?

Answer (score 1):

Simply `if(b)` will be executed if b is true.

`if(!b)` will be executed if b is false.

`if(statement)`...... the statement  should be true for the executing the if statement.